# SyntaxError: illegal character while loading jquery popup in cakephp

Tags: jquery-plugins, cakephp-2.0, popupwindow

I am trying to integrate popup plugin from  `https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Popup-Plugin`. I just followed exactly as said on the above link. I am trying to load a element in popup hence i used this `$this->Popup->link('click me', array('element' => 'my_element'));`
but when i load on the browser i get this following error which i have no clue about it and i have been trying to fix this for last two days and pls help me resolve this error

```
SyntaxError: illegal character
...eldset>\r\n\t<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"$('#popup_1').show(); return false;\">click...
```

and any other possible solution to this would be appriciated.

Comment: What's in `app/views/elements/my_element.ctp`? I see some backslashes in the output that probably shouldn't be there... Is it possible you've used a single-quoted string somewhere that you meant to use a double quoted string?

Comment: i have created a signup form in myelement.ctp

Comment: well I will suggest use simplest popup instead of plugin, see http://webdesignandsuch.com/how-to-create-a-popup-with-css-and-javascript/ in this if want help I can help you

Comment: @Anubhav  thanks i would need ur help...

Answer (score 0):

Ok then see how implement webdesignandsuch.com/how-to-create-a-popup-with-css-and-javascript/

Now read the implementation from the above link, now what you have to do in cakephp is given below:

Step 1: Add these two lines in your layout file, lets say you are using default layout then inside body tags add:

```
 <div id="blanket" style="display:none"></div>
 <div id="popUpDiv" style="display:none">
```

These two lines will be used to create popup div and blanket

Step 2: Now You will see css-pop.js file there is one function

```
  function popup(windowname) {
         blanket_size(windowname);
         window_pos(windowname);
         toggle('blanket');
         toggle(windowname);        
  }
```

So you have to make one ajax request to get HTML of popup as example is shown below

```
$.ajax({
      url: "test.html",
         context: document.body
     }).done(function(data) {
      $('#popUpDiv').html(data);
      popup('popUpDiv');
     });
```

data would be html code which is a response of your ajax request.

Step 3: Create url of ajax request, lets sat ajax_signup.html

```
   echo all the html part followed by exit.
```

Now you get an idea what I am trying to explain!